# Populate picker with sqlite data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I wont to populate pickerview from data stored in sqlite

Comment: there is no any direct method for that ..... your question should be ... how to get data from sqlite and the another one how to populate pickerView .. try this question you will find answer to both here ..

Comment: You have to run select query and have to save data in sort of NSString, NSMutableArray or other data type, then those will be handled and populate the picker,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First retrieve the data from the SQLite DB and store them in a proper structure. You can then use it to populate the Picker.